# Password-protected APK installation?

Tags: security, apk, lineageos, lenovo, password-protection

I am seeking ways to disable installing apps with APK, i.e. make the setting "Allow apps from unknown sources" password-protected or disable completely for user.
Is there a way? Maybe it's possible from adb shell?

I am running LinageOS 13 on Lenovo Vibe A Plus and can flash 14.1 if needed.

Comment: Work Profile or Fully-Managed device.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your idea? I searched and found nothing like work profile on LineageOS, only [system profile](https://imgur.com/a/GbwOwLu)

Comment: It's a corporate level solution. If you are not already familiar with it, it's certainly not for you: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=block+app+installation+in+Android+work+profile. You can try some other solutions already suggested in similar questions: https://android.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=block%20app%20installation. But I don't think any universal reliable solution exists.

Comment: yes, corporate solutions are definitely an overkill for this task, I considered to utilize Lineage builtin functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel I found a solution to my problem. Though it is not exactly what is in the question title it perfectly does the job.

In the LineageOS there is a special setting that is located in
the *Settings>Privacy* menu, this setting is called **Protected apps**

[image]

In this applet you can specify any app and protect it with pattern.

[image]

Just literally ANY, including **Settings**, which perfectly fits my needs. If the user cannot enter the settings he cannot install APK as well!